# Bitmanipulation

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I need a javascript-function which convert 
a 4 Byte HEX String to BIN(use a Part auf the Bytes) to DEC

These data come from a sensor and the measured values are distributed in this string.

example ("ff027608", BitOffset=7,BitSize=4)

11111111000000100111011000001000 -> 1000 -> 8 (DEC)

-----------^^^^

Starting at Offset 7 is a 4 Bit Value

```
function convert(bp,BitOffset,BitSize){
  bp >>= parseFloat(BitOffset);
  bp <<= parseFloat(BitSize);
  return bp;
};
```

1) How do I convert Hex to Long Integer

2) How to cut out the 4-byte value ICHD

3) How do I convert it to a DEC

Or is there a better way

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please accept one of the answers.  Click on the big tick next to the best one.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from hex do dec with:

```
var dec = parseInt(hex, 16);
```

and from dec to hex with

```
var hex = dec.toString(16);
```

and from bin to dec with

```
var dec = parseInt(bin, 2);
```

and from dec to bin with

```
var bin = dec.toString(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier way:

```
function convert(input, offset, size){
    var result = input.substr(offset, size);
    result = parseInt(result, 2);

    return result;
}
```

You can convert hex to in using `parseInt(hex, 16)`, but I'm affraid JS doesn't support longs (AFAIK). If you need long, probably you must split it into two ints.